# Добавить jar другого проекта в зависимость Maven

Tags: java, maven

У меня есть 2 проекта, и один использует другой. Сборка jar идет через Maven.
Проект я подключил как dependency в таком стиле:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.roufid.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Jar перебрасывается в папку lib, но не прописывается в манифест (причем только он).

Подключен плагин maven-jar-plugin со следующими настройками:

```
<mainfest>
    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
    <mainClass>...</mainClass>
</mainfest>
```

**Как его всетаки заставить не только копировать jar в lib, но и прописывать его в манифесте?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависимости из **scope** **system** не будут помещаться в **jar**.

Я вижу несколько решений этой задачи:

1. Вы делаете **example-app** подмодулем вашего основного проекта и прописываете зависимость как `compile`
2. Вы помещаете **example-app** в локальный репозиторий (`mvn install`) и прописываете зависимость как `compile`

На мой взгляд это будет идеологически правильно.

Comment: Тогда ругается на присутствие <systemPath>. Грит только при scope System можно его указывать.

Comment: изменил ответ полностью

Comment: Я сильно сопротивлялся переносу модуля в репозиторий, но это оказался самый адекватный вариант из найденных. Честно, Maven меня этим сильно огорчил. Самое банальное, а не может.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim у него такая идеология. Попробуйте gradle - может вам больше подойдёт.